# How to find elements by attribute namespace in XPath

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I'm trying to use XPath to find all elements that have an element in a given namespace.

For example, in the following document I want to find the `foo:bar` and `doodah` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:foo="http://foo.example.com">
  <foo:bar quux="value">Content</foo:bar>
  <widget>Content</widget>
  <doodah foo:quux="value">Content</doodah>
</root>
```

I know I can use the following XPath expression to load all attributes from a given namespace:

```
"//@*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com']"
```

However:

- This doesn't give me the elements, just the attributes.
- Where elements contain multiple attributes from that namespace, this selector will return a result per-attribute rather than per-element

Is it possible to get what I want, or do I  have to gather the attributes and calculate the unique set of elements they correspond to?

Comment: Did you forgot to add a namespace for doodah? Because I don't see how it can be selected through a namespace.

Comment: If the clarifications weren't clear, I used the wrong namespace in my original example. My mistake.

Comment: Thanks for this post, it really helped.

To sum up:

- To get elements with attributes from a given namespace:  
`//*[@*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com']]`

- To get attributes from a given namespace:  
`//@*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com']`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use:

```
//*[namespace-uri()='yourNamespaceURI-here'
   or
    @*[namespace-uri()='yourNamespaceURI-here']
   ]
```

the predicate two conditions are or-ed with the XPath `or` operator.

The XPath expression  thus selects any element that either:

- belongs to the specified namespace.
- has attributes that belong to the specified namespace.

Comment: It was only the second half of that I needed :) I didn't know you could nest predicates in predicates. Have updated my post accordingly

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev could you pls have a look here is this a namespace problem? tnx  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007767/iphone-sdk-xml-mystery-after-adding-child-nodeforxpath-returns-nothing

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but by only deleting one char in your XPath you get all elements in a certain namespace:

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com']
```

Comment: does not match attrubutes in that namespace

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
//*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com' or @*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com']]
```

It will give you element foo:bar and element doodah (if you change `tal:quux` to `foo:quux` in your XML-data):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:foo="http://foo.example.com" xmlns:tal="xxx">
  <foo:bar quux="value">Content</foo:bar>
  <widget>Content</widget>
  <doodah foo:quux="value">Content</doodah>
</root>
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Not quite so... namespace-uri(./@*)='http://foo.example.com'] returns true only if the first attribute (which is implementation dependent!) belongs to that namespace. The original post wants the element to be selected if *any* of its attributes belongs to the namespace

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression is almost perfect. Instead of asking for attributes "@*" ask for elements "*" and it should work:

```
"//*[namespace-uri()='http://foo.example.com']"
```

Comment: You haven't understood the question. The OP wants any element to be selected, that either belongs to the namespace or has ot least one attribute that belongs to the namespace. Your expression doesnt select an element that has attributes in the namespace but the element doesnt belong to the namespace

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I know that I haven't understood the question as I added a comment to the question asking why "doodah" should be selected.