# How to use Javascript to find namespaced HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I am writing something academic where I have namespaced HTML elements like:

```
<ns:LinkList id="sitesuteis" cssClass="classone">
            <ns:LinkItem id="LI1" href="http://www.ibt.pt/" target="_blank">IBT</ns:LinkItem>
            <ns:LinkItem id="LI2" href="http://http://html5demos.com/t/" target="_blank">HTML5 Demos</ns:LinkItem>
            <ns:LinkItem id="LI3" href="http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/" target="_blank">Dive into HTML5</ns:LinkItem>
            <ns:LinkItem id="LI4" href="http://html5boilerplate.com/" target="_blank">HTML5 Boilerplate</ns:LinkItem>
        </ns:LinkList>
```

Now, in JavaScript I am trying:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('ns:LinkItem');
element = elements[0];
console.log(element.getAttribute('id'));
//I get a correct value in all browsers
```

to get all the ChildNodes in my `elements[0]`. It works fine in all browsers, except -IE lt 9-

I tried:

```
var children = element.getElementsByTagName('ns:LinkItem');
console.log(children.length);
```

and:

```
var children = Array();
for (i=0; i<element.childNodes.length; i++){
   alert(element.childNodes[i].nodeName);
   if (element.childNodes[i].nodeName=="NS:LINKITEM"){
      children.push(element.childNodes[i]);
   }
}
console.log(children.length);
```

In both console.logs, I get the correct length (4) in every browser except Internet Explorer 8 or less where I get 0.

According to @Shadow Wizard, in Internet Explorer 8 and below, the `canHaveChildren` property of the element is false which means dead end, the browser simply doesn't support having child nodes for this tag, same way that `<br />` can't have child nodes for example. I have tried it and it is true. If I try:

```
element.parentNode
```

in Internet Explorer 8 or less, I get the `div` that contains my markup and in the other browsers I get my parent `<ns:LinkList>`.

I really need a hack for this, and I can't seem to find one.

Comment: What version(s) of IE? There is som indication that IE does not always return correct information in some versions.

Comment: if this line correct:  `var children = element.getElementsByTagName(('xrtml:LinkItem');`  you have an extra opening parens, so i just wanted to make sure that's just a typo here and not your code.

Comment: thanks dtan, that was just a typo, i edited the question

Comment: Your example markup doesn't show any children in your LinkItem nodes. Do they actually have children in your actual code?

Comment: could you post the whole html page? I just tried with my IE8 and it worked... check it: http://i51.tinypic.com/3449um9.png

Answer (score 2):

In non-Internet Explorer browsers, I would recommend `getElementsByTagNameNS` to get the elements in a specific namespace.

In Internet Explorer, you can use XPath instead.

jQuery also provides a way to use namespaces; it seems to be covered in "[jQuery XML parsing with namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853740/jquery-xml-parsing-with-namespaces)".

Comment: thank you, my problem is exclusively with IE and i have to do this within the realm of html+javascript. can't do it with xslt

Comment: Believe me, XPath is what you need. Take a look at those two links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529556/xpath-find-elements-by-attribute-namespace

Comment: @André, what do you mean by term "within the realm of html+javascript" - in IE you have the possibility to use xpath in javascript/jscript (whatever)

Comment: Did you get any results/bugs?

Answer (score 1):

In Internet Explorer 8 and below, the `canHaveChildren` property of the element is `false` which means dead end, the browser simply doesn't support having child nodes for this tag, same way that `<br />` can't have child nodes for example.

This has been fixed in Internet Explorer 9 though.

Comment: so, isn't there a way to solve this in versions earlier than 9?

Comment: Maybe something with `DTD` but I didn't really look into it.

Answer (score 1):

I never had this issue, so this is rather just a proposal or hint.

I found "[getElementsByTagName (W3C DOM Core method)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/getElementsByTagName)" for MSIE namespace "restriction".

I finally found the point in "[XPath in JavaScript, Part 3](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/04/04/xpath-in-javascript-part-3/)" that would confirm XPath use would be the point:

> By default, Internet Explorer’s XPath engine doesn’t work with
>   namespaces (the same as the DOM Level 3 XPath implementation).
>   Namespace information must be specified ahead of time as a property on
>   the XML DOM document object itself. Consider the following XML code:
>
> ```
> <books xmlns:wrox="http://www.wrox.com/"
> xmlns="http://www.amazon.com/">
>     <wrox:book>Professional JavaScript</book> </books>
> ```
>
> In order to use XPath queries on this document, you’d first need to
>   define namespace information for the wrox and default namespaces. You
>   can do so via the setProperty() method, passing in
>   "SelectionNamespaces" and a space-separated string of namespace
>   declarations. Example:
>
> ```
> xmldoc.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces",
>     "xmlns:wrox='http://www.wrox.com/' xmlns='http://www.amazon.com/'"); var book =
> xmldoc.documentElement.selectSingleNode("wrox:book");
> ```
>
> Note that the namespace declarations are in the same format as they
>   appear in the XML. Unfortunately, there is no automatic way to extract
>   the namespace information from the document for use with XPath
>   queries. Conclusion
>
> Internet Explorer does have XPath support, but it comes with several
>   caveats. First is that XPath queries only work on XML documents, not
>   on HTML documents and therefore can’t be used on document to help find
>   elements on the page. Second, the XPath implementation is very basic
>   and allows only basic return types (nodes and NodeSet objects). Still,
>   if you’re dealing with XML data, XPath remains a fast and convenient
>   way to find specific elements without walking the DOM manually.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following function should work - I've used it in a previous project, and I believe it works effectively in Internet Explorer 6, 7, and 8. I don't have a good way to test in Internet Explorer 9, but I'm guessing it should work properly, as [Internet Explorer 9 supports `getElementsByTagNameNS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's pretty straightforward, and relies on core browser methods.

```
/**
 * Cross-browser implementation for namespaced tags
 * @param {DOM Node} n          Parent node
 * @param {String} tag          Tag name you're trying to retrieve
 * @param {String} [ns]         Namespace prefix
 */
getElementsByTagName = function(n, tag, ns) {
    // map the namespace prefix to the full namespace URIs
    var nsMap = {
        'svg': 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
        // etc - whatever's relevant for your page
    };
    if (!ns) {
        // no namespace - use the standard method
        return n.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    }
    if (n.getElementsByTagNameNS && nsMap[ns]) {
        // function and namespace both exist
        return n.getElementsByTagNameNS(nsMap[ns], tag);
    }
    // no function, get with the colon tag name
    return n.getElementsByTagName(ns + ':' + tag);
};

// get a list of svg:circle elements
getElementsByTagName(document, 'circle', 'svg');
```

The only pain point here is the requirement to define a mapping from the namespace prefix to the full namespace URI. If you want to make this a more portable function, you could have `nsMap` be a function argument, rather than something defined in the function body; or you could refer to a namespace map object in the global context.

Here's a fully modularized version, with a slightly tighter version of `getElementsByTagName`:

```
var namespaces = (function() {
    var nsMap = {};

    /**
     * Add a new XML namespace with prefix
     * @param {String} prefix       Prefix for new namespace
     * @param {String} uri          Full URI of new namespace
     */
    function addNamespace(prefix, uri) {
        nsMap[prefix] = uri;
    }

    /**
     * Cross-browser implementation for namespaced tags
     * @param {DOM Node} [n]        Parent node
     * @param {String} tag          Tag name you're trying to retrieve
     * @param {String} [ns]         Namespace prefix
     */
    function getElementsByTagName(n, tag, ns) {
        return !ns ?
            n.getElementsByTagName(tag) :
            (n.getElementsByTagNameNS && nsMap[ns]) ?
                n.getElementsByTagNameNS(nsMap[ns], tag) :
                n.getElementsByTagName(ns + ':' + tag);
    }

    return {
        addNamespace: addNamespace,
        getElementsByTagName: getElementsByTagName
    };
}());

// set the svg namespace
namespaces.addNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
// get a list of svg:circle elements
namespaces.getElementsByTagName(document, 'circle', 'svg');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack, but it might be robust enough for what you need:

```
function getElementsByTagName(parent, tagName)
{
    if(typeof parent.canHaveChildren === 'undefined' || parent.canHaveChildren)
    {
        return parent.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    }

    var elements = [];
    var cursor = parent;
    while(cursor.nextSibling && cursor.nextSibling.tagName !== ('/' + parent.tagName))
    {
        if(cursor.tagName === tagName.toUpperCase())
        {
            elements.push(cursor);
        }
        cursor = cursor.nextSibling;
    }
    return elements;
}

function getText(parent)
{
    return parent.innerHTML || parent.nextSibling.data;
}
```

For example:

```
var element = document.getElementById('sitesuteis');
var children = getElementsByTagName(element, 'ns:LinkItem');
console.log(children.length);

for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
{
    console.log([getText(children[i]), children[i].getAttribute('href')]);
}
```

Comment: looking at the code, seems absolutely perfect. I'm going to try it out today. thanks

Comment: @André Alçada Padez: Only if you haven't got nested lists, otherwise it stops on the first closing LinkList tag.  This can be fixed by keeping track of opening/closing parent.tagName tags.