# How can I select a DOM element using a partial attribute name?

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, namespaces

I'd like to select a number of elements on a page using `document.selectQueryAll()` or `element.selectQueryAll()` using a partial name for their attributes.

NOTE: NOT using partial attribute value.

WHY?   *(You may know a better way to do this using Namespaces directly???)*

I want to find all elements where

```
<div  xmlns:${prefix}='{a particular namespace value I know}' >
```

etc

I want to figure out what the namespace prefix is, for a particular namespace I know I'm looking for, so then I can go search for sub-elements in that particular namespace.

I'd planned to find the element as described above, figure out the namespace, then go look for my sub-elements

```
querySelectAll( "[typeof='" + ${prefix} + ":" + "Offering" + "'" )
```

so I can find all sub-elements matching this

```
<div typeof="gr:Offering">
```

but I won't know in advance what the XML namespace prefix will be defined to be.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPath to query based on names, since it is namespace aware. For example:

```
document.evaluate( '//@*[contains(local-name(), "data-")]', document, Function, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null )
```

will get all `data-` attributes in the document.

There is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529556/xpath-find-elements-by-attribute-namespace) which may help with the syntax.

Comment: The DOM is in memory and I'm querying it using Javascript and CSS selectors. How can I parse it using XPath?

Comment: There are plenty of solutions, including the native [XPathEvaluator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript#Implementing_a_User_Defined_Namespace_Resolver) as well as utilities such as [e4x.js](https://github.com/eligrey/e4x.js), [AJAXSLT](http://code.google.com/p/ajaxslt/), or [Sarissa](http://dev.abiss.gr/sarissa/)