# Selenium: SVG element embedded into Object tag is not been identified by Selenium IDE or xPath?

Tags: html, xpath, selenium

I have an html segment like this

```
<div id="imageholder>
<object data="1.svg" width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
</div>.
```

When i see the inspect element in Firefox/firebug i can't see the SVG file structure, 
but in Chrome i am able to see the svg file structure like below:

```
<div id="imageholder>
<object data="1.svg" width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke-dasharray="none"
shape-rendering="auto" font-family="'Dialog'" width="4800">
<desc>widthmm=90.48768097536195 heightmm=49.38127063754128</desc>
<g>
<g>....</g>
</g>
```

However, i am not able to locate svg tag or any g element through X-path. I tried with

```
//div[contains(@id='imageholder')]
```

then i get the element correctly.

```
//div[contains(@id='imageholder')/object]
```

also returns element correctly. But

```
//div[contains(@id='imageholder')/object/svg]
```

fails.

My requirement is: I need to click on several g elements of SVG image, but i am not able to reach it.
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Some more details added on:[Dec 8,2011]

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='imageholder']/object"));//This worked correctly 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='imageholder']/object/*[local-name()='svg' and  namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']"));//did not work
```

I also tried all the possible combination [XPath - Find elements by attribute namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529556/xpath-find-elements-by-attribute-namespace) given on this link but could not succeed.
Thanks

For more details, please find the sample code.

## Sample.html

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9;chrome=IE8">
<body>
<div id="imageholder"><object data="1.svg" width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml"></object></div>
</body>
</html>
```

## 1.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN'
    'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd'>
<svg stroke-dasharray="none" shape-rendering="auto" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" font-family="&apos;Dialog&apos;"
 width="4800" text-rendering="auto" fill-opacity="1" contentScriptType="text/ecmascript" color-interpolation="auto"
 color-rendering="auto" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" font-size="12" viewBox="0 0 4800 2619" fill="black"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" stroke="black" image-rendering="auto" stroke-miterlimit="10"
 zoomAndPan="magnify" version="1.0" stroke-linecap="square" stroke-linejoin="miter" contentStyleType="text/css"
 font-style="normal" height="2619" stroke-width="1" stroke-dashoffset="0" font-weight="normal" stroke-opacity="1"
    >
<g style="fill-opacity:0.7; stroke:black; stroke-width:0.1cm;">
    <circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:red;"
            transform="translate(0,50)"/>
    <circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:blue;"
            transform="translate(70,150)"/>
    <circle cx="6cm" cy="2cm" r="100" style="fill:green;"
            transform="translate(-70,150)"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Please click on sample.html once you save the files.

Answer (score 2):

`//div[contains(@id='imageholder')/object/svg` fails because you didn't tell the processor that the namespace of the `svg` element is not the same as the other. See the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`.

You can write : `//div[contains(@id,'imageholder')]/object/*[local-name()='svg' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']`.

**EDIT (after reading your update) :**

Problem can be : in your original html file, you have a link to the svg file in your `object` element.

Even if your browser incorporate the svg file in the dom, the XPath expression seems to act on the original file itself (with the href). Sorry, but I'm not aware of those kind of use cases for XPath, and can't tell you more.

Comment: ,Thanks for your response. I tried with above scenario but its still giving me noSuchElement exception. 
As i mentioned earlier, I can see the svg file details only in Chrome browser not in FF(inspect element). Can it be possible that SVG elements are not found via X-path because it is embedded in obejct tag..?:-(

Comment: Concerning your XPath expression, did you notice the problem when you use the  `contains` function ? it's not a `=` but a `,`.

Comment: ,Vincent, I added some more details in Question section [on Dec 8,2011] section. I was not able to add the code properly here.Please have a look and let me know if can help. How can i insert image here to show you the inspect element of chrome. Before svg file on inspect element i see one greyed text (sibling to svg tag)--><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">...Do you feel it can impact anyway.

Comment: It should work, I'm not aware of your XPath implementation, maybe there is a problem with namespace handling in it. Can you provide your complete XML file, please ? And can you try the following XPath expressions :  `//div[@id='imageholder']/object/*` and `//div[@id='imageholder']/object/*[local-name()='svg']`

Comment: Please find the sample code attached. Open sample.html in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for trying Vincent..I will try if i could detach it from object tag/or get the reference to inserted document though not sure:-(...Please do post me if you come across any solution to this kind of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got some work around to get SVG embedded document. It doesn't seems to be possible via WebElement. But through JavaScriptExecutor, we can get the complete DOM reference and through standard DOM pattern it is possible.
Like: We can do->docuemnt.getElementsByTagName('OBJECT').contentDocument. This will give the complete SVG DOM reference.

The link below doesn't seem to be the direct answer of it, but possibility of Sel2.0 can be seen through this.
[Selenium: Can I set any of the attribute value of a WebElement in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium)

Might be helpful for all:-)
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Switch to the default frame before trying to access the SVG tag, i.e frame(0).
Tried many XPath solutions nothing worked, but switching to frame worked as a charm, its treating SVG as a frame here.**

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
    d.navigate().to("file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/sample/svg.html");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    d.switchTo().frame(0);
    Actions builder = new Actions(d);
    WebElement svgObject = d.findElement(By.xpath("(//*[name()='svg']/*[name()='g']/*[name()='circle'])[2]"));
    //"style" here prints the colour of the second circle in the svg tag.  ie( blue circle)
    System.out.println(svgObject.getAttribute("style"));
    System.out.println(svgObject.getAttribute("transform"));
    System.out.println(svgObject.getAttribute("cx"));
    System.out.println(svgObject.getAttribute("cy"));
    System.out.println(svgObject.getAttribute("r"));
    builder.moveToElement(svgObject).click();
```