# Selenium: Clicking on toaster issues

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on an element on a page; the element is clearly visible on screen. There is a toaster that might pop up, so I'm trying to write a defense: if the toaster is on screen, close the toaster first, then continue clicking through to the next page. I am using PageFactory, so I have an element to contain the toaster and one for the close button for the toaster. My "deal with toaster" method is as follows:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#toaster")).size() > 0 
    && toaster.isDisplayed()) {
    toasterClose.click();
}
```

When I do this in chrome, however, I'm getting `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (994, 758)`

Pausing the test execution, I cannot see the toaster on the screen. I figure the devs must be hiding it by making it render in a far away, unscrollable location. So as a stopgap measure,  I added a condition that if the x coordinate was greater than 800, don't click. With that in place, I get:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (547, 725). Other element would receive the click: <div id="toaster">...</div>
```

What's going on? How can the toaster not be clickable but would somehow receive the click anyway? Firefox can handle the test just fine, with or without the 800 pixel workaround; it's only Chrome having this issue.

**For Clarification:** The goal of the test is NOT to click the toaster. The goal is to click another element on the page. The test reported that a toaster was in the way, so I attempted to write a step to close the toaster if it is displayed. I have not seen this toaster, so I'm not exactly sure what it is, but chrome keeps reporting that it's in the way. All our toasters site-wide use a basic template that includes a close button so the user can close the toaster, which is what I'm trying to click. Firefox never has this issue and does not report the existence of any toasters.

I'm calling it a toaster because that's what our site calls it, because that's what it's called in whatever framework we got it from (jQuery UI? Backbone?). If I pause execution, I cannot see any toasters at this point in the test, but jQuery tells me it exists and is visible. However, the element found with jQuery has just the default pieces of our toaster setup: a div, an empty div where the message should be, and the close button. Clearly it's not meant to be rendered at this time, but Chrome thinks it's in the way.

Comment: Interesting. What does `toasterClose.isDisplayed()` say? Does the toaster somehow slide into the screen, or does it (dis)appear instantly? Are we in an inframe? Some older Webdriver had problems with calculating the correct click coordinates in an iframe.

Comment: Any updates? Have any of my suggestions below helped?

Comment: @Kache Sorry, I've been ill, I'll get back to this tomorrow once I'm in front of the system again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the toaster was partially rendered and fixed to the DOM just below the bottom edge of the screen, using position:fixed to stop it from showing up until it's ready to be populated with data and animated onto the screen. When chrome tried to click on links that were below the bottom edge of the screen, it predicted that it'd hit the toaster and didn't actually bother scrolling.

After some googling, I added the following utility function:

```
public static void ScrollElementIntoView(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
}
```

Then I call this method before clicking any link on that page, and voila, no more toaster problems!

Comment: Oh, ha! This is pretty much exactly the scrollbar problem I half-mentioned. I was debating on whether or not to elaborate on it. I guess if I had, it could've been the the answer to you question. I'll update my answer with some details though, in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming by "toaster" you mean some sort of javascript modal popup with a close button.

**Identifying the correct problem**
You're testing the existence and visibility of the `#toaster` element, but not the `toasterClose` element that you're clicking. There's no guarantee that just because one element exists and is displayed, another is as well. From the error, it appears that the `#toaster` element overlaps the `toasterClose` element, making it unclickable.

**Troubleshooting clickability**
Once you've properly selected `toasterClose`, manually use devtools and inspect to see why it's unclickable. Is it visible and unobstructed? Is the `toasterClose` element something of zero height/width? Is there dynamic JavaScript modifying the page post-load? Is it actually positioned in view of the page? (I've had elements render visibly at the edge of the window only to be obstructed by the browser's scroll bars.<sup>1</sup>)

**Alternative**
You should also see if you really need to use this `toasterClose` element. How does would a human close this popup? Would they press `Escape`? Would they click outside the popup window, on the overlay element? Do they do something else that triggers some sort of `closeModal()` javascript function? You can also do any of these things using Selenium.

**Last Resort**
One thing you can *always* do to remove such a popup is to run your own javascript to modify the DOM and remove the offending element(s) altogether:

```
driver.execute_script(<<-javascript)
  var toaster = document.getElementById("toaster");
  toaster.parentNode.removeChild(toaster);

  var overlay = document.getElementById("modal_overlay");
  overlay.parentNode.removeChild(overlay);
javascript
```

**Future/Additional**
If this is a regular issue for you, I would suggest wrapping this code in try/catches and a retry mechanism to make it resilient to javascript dynamically loaded elements.

<sup>1</sup> **Update**
Just to elaborate on the scrollbar issue I had, because it turned out that it was a very similar problem to yours.

[image: A button is out of view]
Here, the "I'm Feeling Lucky" button is out of view. If Selenium tries to click on it, first it will attempt to scroll it into view.

[image: Scrolling a button into view]
Here's an example of what Selenium would attempt to do. Notice how the button is now "in view".

[image: But the button is obscured by the scrollbar]
However, Chrome on OSX is styled in such a way that the scrollbars are normally hidden. The moment that Selenium issues the scroll command, the scrollbars appear and the following click command fails to reach the button.

The solution was to use javascript to scroll the window manually:

```
page.execute_script(<<-javascript)
  document.getElementById("gbqfsb").scrollIntoView(true);
  // or if that doesn't work:
  window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById("gbqfsb").getBoundingClientRect().top);
javascript
```

Comment: ToasterClose is contained within the #toaster element. When I pause execution and examine the screen with my eyeballs, I do not see a toaster anywhere. toasterClose is a big [X] button in the corner of the toaster, where they'd click to close it.

Comment: I'm giving you the bounty, however, for mentioning scrollbars, since that's what led me to figure out the real problem

Comment: Oh, nice. What was the actual problem then? Did you end up having to scroll/resize the browser window?

Comment: yeah, I had to scroll. I added a self-answer explaining why

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Should work:

```
if (driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#toaster")).size() > 0 
    && toaster.isDisplayed()) {

    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(toasterClose).moveByOffset(2,2).click().build().perform();

}
```

Comment: Why? What does this do that toasterClose.click() doesn't? What's the thought behind this solution?

Comment: I faced a similar issue few days back where some parts of a cross icon was NOT clickable and had to move around that element to get to the point where cross icon is clickable to make the click event work. Thought of something similar here.

Comment: One question @Yamikuronue : Did that suggested solution work for you?

Comment: It won't, the toaster is not being displayed on the screen so it's not the same problem you had. I appreciate the info though

Answer (score 0):

Can you close toaster using escape key from keyboard manually.
If you can than use following:

`Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.ESCAPE).build().perform();`

Comment: The toaster is not visibly open, so I'm not sure?