# How to use javascript to set attribute of selected web element using selenium Webdriver using java?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to use javascript to set attribute for selected element on webpage.

I have found 2 ways to set attribute using javascript

1

```
   WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("document.getElementByID('//id of element').setAttribute('attr', '10')");
```

2

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
    String contents = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

But I want to apply javascript to specific webelement which i have found using selenium webdriver

as an example i have select one link using selenium webdriver

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click ME"))
```

Now I want to set attribute of this webelement using javascript

but I don't know how to combine both

please help me to find solution

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Along the lines of:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click ME"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('attr', '10')",element);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced a similar issue and I have used the javascript Executor

so in my case, I have a list of elements on which I have to change one property

here first I am finding the element, then traversing through the list, and creating a javascriptExecutor object and then executing the script on that particular element

```
//arguments[0] means the element
//arguments[1] means the property
//arguments[2] means the new value of the propert


List<WebElement> unselectableDiv = driver
                .findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-6']"));

        for (WebElement element : unselectableDiv) {

            // System.out.println( "**** Checking the size of div "+unselectableDiv.size());

            JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

            String scriptSetAttr = "arguments[0].setAttribute(arguments[1],arguments[2])";

            js.executeScript(scriptSetAttr, element, "unselectable", "off");

            System.out.println(" *****   check value of Div property " + element.getAttribute("unselectable"));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code trials:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click ME"))
```

The `innerHTML` seems to be set as **Click ME**.

So, to set a new value e.g. `10` as the `innerHTML` you can use the [`executeScript()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method of the [JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089) interface and you can use the following solution:

- Using *innerHTML*:

  ```
  WebDriver driver;
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click ME"));
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  jse.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML', '10')", element);
  ```

Ideally, you need to you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and and you can use the following solution:

- Using *textContent*:

  ```
  WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Click ME")))
  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('textContent','10')", element);
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)