# Click on hidden element Selenium webdriver(javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<tr id="mytr">
   <td id="Table" onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl';" onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm'" class="menulevel1norm" onclick="PopupWin('Left',divMenu2011,this,'.menuitempopuprownormal','.menuitempopuprowhighlight','','.menuitempopupscroll' &nbsp;Alerts&nbsp </td>
      <div id=" divMenu2011 " name="actiondiv " style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border: ">
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/exception.search' ; "> Alert Search</DIV>
      </div>
   <td id="Table " onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl' ; " onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm' "  class="menulevel1norm " onclick="PopupWin( 'Left',divMenu2012,this, '.menuitempopuprownormal', '.menuitempopuprowhighlight', '', '.menuitempopupscroll'); "> &nbsp;Inventory&nbsp;</td>
   <div id="divMenu2012 " name="actiondiv " style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border: ">
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/inventoryaudit.search' ; ">  Inventory Audits</DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/inventory.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=YIMD080' ; "> Adjust Inventory</DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/itemsupsearch.search' ; "> Item Suppression Console</DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/additemsuppression.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=TGTOMSSCFD008' ; "> Add Item Suppression</DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/ProtectItem.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=TGTPID001' ; "> Add Protected Qty</DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/ProtectItem.search' ; "> Protected Qty Console   </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/ProtectItemAudit.search' ; ">    Protected Qty Audit Console </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/MCAFeeds.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=A001' ; ">   Upload MCA Store Feed </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/MCAFeeds.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=A002' ; "> Upload MCA Item Feed </DIV>
   </div>
   <td id="Table " onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl' ; " onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm' "  class="menulevel1norm " onclick="PopupWin( 'Left',divMenu2013,this, '.menuitempopuprownormal', '.menuitempopuprowhighlight', '', '.menuitempopupscroll'); "> &nbsp;RTAM Exclusion&nbsp; </td>
   <div id="divMenu201404150720371518959 " name="actiondiv " style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border: ">
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/Exclusion.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=D002' ; ">  RTAM Exclusion  </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/Exclusion.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=001' ; "> Start RTAM Exclusion  </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/Exclusion.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=D004' ; "> Remove  Excluded Items </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/Exclusion.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=D003' ; ">  Enter  Exclusion Removal </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/Exclusion.detail?CurrentDetailViewID=D009' ; "> Schedule RTAMExclusion   </DIV>
   </div>
   <td id="Table " onmouseover="this.className='menulevel1hl' ; " onmouseout="this.className='menulevel1norm' "  class="menulevel1norm " onclick="PopupWin( 'Left',divMenu2014,this, '.menuitempopuprownormal', '.menuitempopuprowhighlight', '', '.menuitempopupscroll'); ">     &nbsp;Sales Order&nbsp;   </td>
   <div id="divMenu2014 " name="actiondiv " style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;border: ">
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/order.search' ; "> Sales Order Console   </DIV>
      <DIV  myonclick="window.parent.location.href='/smcfs/console/shipment.search' ; "> Outbound Shipment Console</DIV>
   </div>
```

I am trying to click on Ship Order Console. Please find the code below

```
WebElement ele1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tr[@id='mytr']/td[4]"));
ele1.click();
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='divMenu2014']/div[1]"));
String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript(js, ele); 
System.out.println("element is " + ele.getText());
ele.click();
```

When I am printing the `ele.gettext()`, I am getting "sales order console", but when I am trying to click on it it is moving to inventory tab.

Could any one point out where it is going wrong?

Comment: You can try WebElement ele =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@myonclick,'window.parent.location.href') and contains(text(),'Outbound Shipment Console')]"));ele.click();

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Same goes for code. Please clean it up and properly indent it before posting. Thanks!

Comment: I am able to select the link with the above xpath.but when I am trying to click on the element it is moving to inventory..so want to know where the script went wrong

Answer (score 1):

Check this link to set attribute to web element,
[How to use javascript to set attribute of selected web element using selenium Webdriver using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934703/how-to-use-javascript-to-set-attribute-of-selected-web-element-using-selenium-we)

Alternatively, you can click using Javascript without making it visible. I have used CSS selector for your element.

```
executor.executeScript("$(\"div#divMenu2014>div\").click();");
```