# Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

Please advise if this approach is accepted to pick-up date using Selenium

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");

Thread.sleep(3000);

JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);

js.executeScript ("document.getElementById('ctl00_mainContent_view_date1').removeAttribute('readonly',0);"); 

WebElement onwards_date = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_view_date1"));
        onwards_date.clear();
        onwards_date.sendKeys("28/02"); 

js.executeScript ("document.getElementById('ctl00_mainContent_view_date2').removeAttribute('readonly',0);"); 

WebElement return_Date = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_view_date2"));
        return_Date.clear();
        return_Date.sendKeys("27/03");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pick-up a date within the **DEPART DATE** field in the website https://www.spicejet.com/ using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s [executeScript()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) method from [JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089) you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name$= 'txt_Fromdate']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", element);
    WebElement newElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name$= 'txt_Fromdate']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','28/02')", newElement);
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spicejetDepartureDate]

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818820/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-new-attribute-with-a-value-to-an-element-using-selenium/63820053#63820053)
- [How to use javascript to set attribute of selected web element using selenium Webdriver using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934703/how-to-use-javascript-to-set-attribute-of-selected-web-element-using-selenium-we/63739527#63739527)
- [Python - How to edit href attribute in source code before clicking using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894182/python-how-to-edit-href-attribute-in-source-code-before-clicking-using-seleniu/63937415#63937415)

Answer (score 2):

You can set value using JavaScript to input with `ctl00_mainContent_txt_Fromdate` id for **from date** and `ctl00_mainContent_txt_Todate` id for **to date**. You'll not see value changing from UI, but it works.

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]",
    driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_txt_Fromdate")), "28-02-2020");
```

Instead of using `sleep` in you code, use `WebDriverWait` that makes WebDriver wait for a certain condition and will wait only as long as required.

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");

// Wait for Search button to be clickable, the state in which we assume that the site has loaded
WebElement searchButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_btn_FindFlights")));

// Select From and To Cities

js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]",
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_txt_Fromdate")), "28-02-2020");

js.executeScript("arguments[0].value = arguments[1]",
        driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_mainContent_txt_Todate")), "01-03-2020");

searchButton.click();
```