# The method parseDouble(String) is undefined for the type Arc2D

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, double, hidden

I got this error when I am converting the String to double, I want that value in Double data type

This is my code

```
WebElement Rm_rate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MT10']//input[@value= '4424']/following::input[@name = 'avgDiscountRate1']"));
String  r1_rate = Rm_rate.getAttribute("value");
room_rate = Double.parseDouble(r1_rate); //
```

The wave element is

```
<input type="hidden" value="1000.00" name="avgDiscountRate1">
```

Answer (score 0):

You were close enough. You need to initialize the variable **`room_rate`** first.

```
WebElement Rm_rate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MT10']//input[@value= '4424']/following::input[@name = 'avgDiscountRate1']"));
String  r1_rate = Rm_rate.getAttribute("value");
double room_rate = Double.parseDouble(r1_rate);
```

In a single line:

```
double room_rate = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MT10']//input[@value= '4424']/following::input[@name = 'avgDiscountRate1']")).getText());
```

---

However the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) seems to have the attribute `type="hidden"`. So you need to [`removeAttribute()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690) the *`type`* attribute and you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement Rm_rate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MT10']//input[@value= '4424']/following::input[@name = 'avgDiscountRate1']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('type')", Rm_rate);
double room_rate = Double.parseDouble(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='MT10']//input[@value= '4424']/following::input[@name = 'avgDiscountRate1']")).getText());
```

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB but it doesn't work have already declared room_rate as Double at the top

Comment: @KrashnakantLowanshi Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Thanks but still no luck, both solution do not work actually it's getting the Value attribute as String but  not converting that String to the Double data type.