# Error:javascript error: missing ) after argument list using removeAttribute() not working Selenium and Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WebElement  datedelete=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-0']"));

js.executeScript("document.getElementBypath('//input[@id='mat-input-0']').removeAttribute('readonly');","datedelete");
```

Error:javascript error: missing ) after argument list

Comment: "datedelete" Not sure if this is supposed to be in "".

Answer (score 0):

You have already located the element as *`datedelete`* as follows:

```
WebElement  datedelete = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='mat-input-0']"));
```

You just need to pass the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) as an argument:

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", datedelete);
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)