# How to uncheck dynamic checkbox using Selenium Java

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, checkbox

I have  month dropdown where all the month that appears in the dropdown will be selected by default. The question is, I want only `2050-Jan` month  checkbox  to remain checked and want the other month checkbox to be unchecked. Please note that the Year and Month is Dynamic. i.e. if the dropdown has 3  options displayed then the same dropdown can have 2 options displayed or could have more than 3 options displayed.
But the only thing is the Year and month `2050-Jan` alone should remain to be unchecked.

So this being the case how do I uncheck the other two or more checkbox.

Automating in Java selenium any leads will be very helpful.

For now if you see the below dropdown has 3 month and Year option selected by default of which I would need only `2050-Jan` to remain unchecked.

This is a dynamic dropdown where the Year and Month will change but 2050-Jan will always be there but cant say if this will come as 3rd option always

HTML:

```
<mat-option _ngcontent-vor-c141="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-option-multiple ng-tns-c92-121 ng-star-inserted mat-selected mat-active" id="mat-option-370" tabindex="0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false" style="">
    <mat-pseudo-checkbox class="mat-pseudo-checkbox mat-option-pseudo-checkbox ng-star-inserted mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked"></mat-pseudo-checkbox>
    <!---->
    <span class="mat-option-text">2022-Apr</span>
    <!---->
    <div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple"></div>
</mat-option>
```

Dropdown List HTML:

```
<div class="mat-select-arrow-wrapper ng-tns-c92-121">

<div class="mat-select-arrow ng-tns-c92-121"></div></div>
```

HTML after unselecting the checkbox with `April 2022`:

```
<mat-option _ngcontent-vor-c141="" role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-option-multiple ng-tns-c92-121 ng-star-inserted mat-active" id="mat-option-370" tabindex="0" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false" style="">
    <mat-pseudo-checkbox class="mat-pseudo-checkbox mat-option-pseudo-checkbox ng-star-inserted"></mat-pseudo-checkbox>
    <!---->
    <span class="mat-option-text">2022-Apr</span>
    <!---->
    <div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple"></div>
</mat-option>
```

Comment: Can you provide HTML?

Comment: The HTML code of drop down list

Comment: @NandanA - Have added html code for dropdownlist as well

Comment: @NandanA - Any inputs?

Comment: Update the question with the additional HTML of the **2022-Apr** element when it is unchecked.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium - have added the html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uncheck the desired [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) you can [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447) on the element with text as **2022-Apr** using the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//mat-option//span[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='2022-Apr']//preceding-sibling::mat-pseudo-checkbox[1]"))).click();
```

---

As an alternative you can use [`removeAttribute`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60409690/7429447) method to remove the *classname* *`mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked`* as follows:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-option//span[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='2022-Apr']//preceding-sibling::mat-pseudo-checkbox[1]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class')", element);
WebElement newElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//mat-option//span[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='2022-Apr']//preceding-sibling::mat-pseudo-checkbox[1]"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','mat-pseudo-checkbox mat-option-pseudo-checkbox ng-star-inserted')", newElement);
```

Comment: Have a Question - After setting the attribute when i try to click on the checkbox it is not happening is there something else that i need to do

Comment: Hmmm, I suspected this may happen. Honestly using JavaScript wasn't the ideal approach, should have used the regular _`click`_

Comment: so what is the alternate ?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Thank you for the help made changes to the script where i first go and uncheck the checkbox and then check the required checkbox alone using click method thank you for the help @undetected Selenium

Comment: My Code:List<WebElement> checkboxElem = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-option-text')]/preceding-sibling::mat-pseudo-checkbox[contains(@class,'mat-pseudo-checkbox-checked')]"));
    
    for(int i =0;i<checkboxElem.size();i++)
    {
     checkboxElem.get(i).click();
    }
    DriverUtil.waitTime(1500);
    
      WebElement checkbox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='2050-Jan']//preceding-sibling::mat-pseudo-checkbox")); 
     
      checkbox.click();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246665/discussion-between-jay-m-and-undetected-selenium).