# Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, setattribute

Here's the HTML

```html
<img src="//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/220cc817.jpg" width="408" height="605" vspace="" hspace="" border="0" alt="">
```

I am trying to add 3 new attributes to make it like

```html
<img src="//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/220cc817.jpg" width="408" height="605" vspace="" hspace="" border="0" alt="" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" data-mce-style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" data-mce-selected="1">
```

I want to add:

- `style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"`
- `data-mce-style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"` and
- `data-mce-selected="1"`

I tried:

```
image = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.mce-content-body#tinymce > p/a/img")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].style='display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'", image)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].data-mce-style='display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'", image)
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].data-mce-selected='1'", image)     ` but got no results nor errors
```

Comment: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/3387/set-attribute-of-an-element-using-webdriver-python

Comment: I tried the following but got no results nor errors
`image = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "body.mce-content-body#tinymce > p/a/img")))`

`browser.execute_script("arguments[0].style='display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'", image)`

`browser.execute_script("arguments[0].data-mce-style='display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'", image)`

`browser.execute_script("arguments[0].data-mce-selected='1'", image) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the three new attributes you need to use [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s `execute_script()` method.

Now, you want to add the following attributes:

- `style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"`
- `data-mce-style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"`
- `data-mce-selected="1"`

The method for adding them would be similar and as a demonstration to add the attribute `data-mce-selected="1"` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[src='//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/220cc817.jpg']")))
  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','28/02')", element)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and in a single line:

  ```
  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-mce-selected','1')", WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//img[@src='//www.shahidpro.tv/uploads/articles/220cc817.jpg']"))))
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)
- [How to use javascript to set attribute of selected web element using selenium Webdriver using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934703/how-to-use-javascript-to-set-attribute-of-selected-web-element-using-selenium-we/63739527#63739527)
- [Python - How to edit href attribute in source code before clicking using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63894182/python-how-to-edit-href-attribute-in-source-code-before-clicking-using-seleniu/63937415#63937415)

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you can find `element` that you want to change.
You can add new attribute using js:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;');", element)
```