# C# Selenium SendKeys not working even with Javascript executor

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

The test finds the element because it doesnt fail but its unable to send the parameters.

Tried following :

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='search']")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='search']")).Click();

IWebElement wb = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@type='search']"));
IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value='QA Test Automation Developer';", wb);
```

Comment: wb.SendKeys("whatever text you want");

Isn't doing anything?

Answer (score 0):

As it is a `<input>` tag you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  IWebElement wb = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input[type='search']")));
  wb.Click();
  wb.Clear();
  wb.SendKeys("QA Test Automation Developer");
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  IWebElement wb = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[@type='search']")));
  wb.Click();
  wb.Clear();
  wb.SendKeys("QA Test Automation Developer");
  ```

---

### Using `IJavaScriptExecutor`

- Using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and `innerHTML`:

  ```
  IWebElement wb = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input[type='search']")));
  IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
  jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML','QA Test Automation Developer')", wb);
  ```
- Using [`setAttribute()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) and `textContext`:

  ```
  IWebElement wb = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("input[type='search']")));
  IJavaScriptExecutor jse = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
  jse.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('textContext','QA Test Automation Developer')", wb);
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818820/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-new-attribute-with-a-value-to-an-element-using-selenium/63820053#63820053)
- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)

Comment: Tried all the above options but still does not work. This is the link I am trying to automate if you can check it out(https://jobs.labcorp.com/).There will be a keyword search and submit that does not seem to find the element.