# How to convert selenium python script in to Selenium Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, setattribute

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notranslate public-DraftEditor-content' and @role='textbox']"))).send_keys("This is auto message example.")
```

Hello, I would like to ask if this can be converted into javascript because I have the whole bot already typed in javascript and only this needs to be converted from selenium python to javascript. Is it possible or do I have to write the whole javascript into selenium?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the line of code from [python](/questions/tagged/python) to [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) notation, you can use the **`setAttribute()`** method and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) and `innerHTML`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notranslate public-DraftEditor-content' and @role='textbox']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('innerHTML','This is auto message example.')", element)
  ```
- Using [`setAttribute()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp) and `textContext`:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='notranslate public-DraftEditor-content' and @role='textbox']")))
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('textContext','This is auto message example.')", element)
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818820/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-new-attribute-with-a-value-to-an-element-using-selenium/63820053#63820053)
- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)