# How to Change a html line code with python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'd like to change this line:

`<button _ngcontent-c19="" class="blue-button-disabled" disabled="">CONTINUE </button>`

to this:

```
<button _ngcontent-c19="" class="blue-button">CONTINUE </button>
```

all that I could do is change the class name from blue-button-disabled to blue-button, but I couldn't remove `disabled=""`

I used this code to achieve that result:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('class','blue-button')", element)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the attribute `disabled=""` you can use the following line of code:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled')", element)
```

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)
- [Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818820/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-new-attribute-with-a-value-to-an-element-using-selenium/63820053#63820053)