# How to change the date of a hidden element of a Datepicker using setAttribute method and Selenium with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, setattribute

I have been struggling for days to find a way to set a date of a datepicker using Selenium with Python.
I found out that there is a hidden element with the date, so I tried javascript executor to set a value to that hidden element. I tried different ways, and the scripts seem to execute fine, but the date doesn't change.

My script looks like this:

```
#input date by using hidden date method 1
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{0}')".format("2019-10-31"), element )
element.submit()
```

and

```
#input date by using hidden date method 2
date = "2019-10-31"
element= browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value", "%s")' % date, element)
element.submit()
```

The HTML code and picture of the website looks like this:

HTML of date picker:
[image: HTML code of date picker]

Date picker element:

[image: Date picker]

Edit:

Updated HTML with the hidden element visible
[image: HTML Code of visible element]

Comment: I would say what you're trying to do is far from ideal - it's basically modifying hidden/private behaviour in tests which is generally a bad idea in any kind of test.


But anyway, to answer your question, have you tried setting the value instead? That's what is sent by the form, not the element attribute.


eg: `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "%s"'...`

(as to why you shouldn't, you can see it yourself: you're finding it hard to debug this case)

Comment: @Official_Ali Is it a public website we can test?

Comment: @Christian I tried the code as you pointed out, but nothing changed. ```browser.execute_script('arguments[0].value = "%s"' % date, element)```

Comment: @DebanjanB No unfortunately it's not :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` element is having the *type* attribute set as **hidden**. You can edit/remove the *type* attribute and set the value as follows:

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('type')", element)
new_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','2019-10-31')", new_element)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to Change a html line code with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731966/how-to-change-a-html-line-code-with-python/64732027#64732027)
- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)
- [Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818820/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-new-attribute-with-a-value-to-an-element-using-selenium/63820053#63820053)

Comment: I tried your suggestion, the code works and you see a new element with the input box on the website, but the date doesn't change. I tried changing setAttribute to value but that didn't work either. ```browser.execute_script("arguments[0].Value =  '2019-10-31'", new_element)```

Comment: @Official_Ali It's not a new element but the hidden element. Can you update the question with the text based HTML of the `<input>` element when it's  visible?

Comment: Just updated my question with a screenshot of the visible element with HTML

Comment: @Official_Ali Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I am getting an error: JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null. Also instead of setattribute I tried value, but also gives me a  null error.

Comment: @Official_Ali There was a bug which I've removed now. Retest and let me know the status please.

Comment: Got a timeout error. Your first piece of code worked better as I was still able to change the date when I just tried, however the dateviewer below did not change with it. I tried to execute the report to see if the output actually shows the date that was set in the hidden element made visible. Will let you know, thanks

Comment: @Official_Ali You want me to revert back the answer to it's initial version?

Comment: Yes please, that one seems to work, but will be verified after I receive the report. WIll update you tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @Official_Ali Minor change, retest once please.

Comment: Still a timeout message received as well as the hidden element not showing up. The previous code seems to work as the output of the report is correct. Please revert back to the code without the wait.

Comment: @Official_Ali Rolled back to it's initial version.

Comment: Just retested, and worked fine. Initially it didn't work for me because I forgot to switch frame. Your code works perfect, thanks