# Unable to click on date on calendar on selenium automation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to click calendar date with JavascriptExecutor

```
   **String dateVal = "November 22, 2020";
    js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='flatpickr-day'and @aria-label='"+dateVal+"']")));**
```

HTML TAGS as seen in inmage
[image]

**What might be the solution for it seeking your feedback?**

Comment: why can't you use click directy ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064715/how-to-change-the-date-of-a-hidden-element-of-a-datepicker-using-setattribute-me?noredirect=1#comment115029401_65064715 This might be helpful

Comment: @Dip Why would you use `arguments[0].click()` instead of the much proven and efficient `click()`

Comment: Thank you both for your response. I'm just trying to click on day(22nd Nov) on calendar control. Problems seem to be finding the element using xpath driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='flatpickr-day'and @aria-label='"+dateVal+"']")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the space in the class name in the dom causing problems? If so try using contains in the xpath like this:

```
   String dateVal = "November 22, 2020";
    js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'flatpickr-day') and @aria-label='"+dateVal+"']")));
```

or just try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'flatpickr-day') and @aria-label='"+dateVal+"']")).click()
```

Comment: Thanks alot DMart it worked with js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'flatpickr-day') and @aria-label='"+dateVal+"']")));