# How to remove the readonly attribute from the input field in python with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am facing issues removing readonly tag from an input field using python and selenium. Can anybody help me here?

Datepicker Image:

[image: Datepicker Image]

HTML:

```
<input autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" type="text" placeholder="Select Date and Time" readonly="readonly" class="ivu-input">
```

This is the code I am tried to use to remove the tag but the tag is still active during the script is running

```
a=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="app"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].removeAttribute(\"readonly\")', a);
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].setAttribute("value", "'+dateString+'")', a);
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `readonly="readonly"` attribute you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ivu-input[placeholder='Select Date and Time']"))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ivu-input' and @placeholder='Select Date and Time']"))))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to change the date of a hidden element of a Datepicker using setAttribute method and Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064715/how-to-change-the-date-of-a-hidden-element-of-a-datepicker-using-setattribute-me/65065407#65065407)
- [How to Change a html line code with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731966/how-to-change-a-html-line-code-with-python/64732027#64732027)
- [Selenium Datepicker using JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406498/selenium-datepicker-using-javascriptexecutor/60409690#60409690)
- [Is there a way to add a new attribute with a value to an element using selenium python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63818820/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-new-attribute-with-a-value-to-an-element-using-selenium/63820053#63820053)