# How to remove an attribute from an element in selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, attributes, recaptcha, 2captcha

HTML:

```
<textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" class="g-recaptcha-response" 
style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 
0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
```

i'm trying to remove the `"display: none"` attribute, how would I go about doing this in the python version of selenium?

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to block to make it visible.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';",elem)
```

Removing would be below where elem is your webelement.

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')",elem)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the display box to input the reCaptcha key visible by replacing the `display` attribute with pretty much anything!

You can do this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
element = driver.find_element_by_id('g-recaptcha-response')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', 'display: true')", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as per below 2 methods

```
String visibility = web.findElement(By.xpath("//your xpath")).getCssValue("display");
```

You will get display value and then you can remove it.
other way to do it using below code.

```
firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
element = firefox.find_element_by_css_selector("this element css selector here")
attributeValue = element.get_attribute("style")
```

Style element you will get and remove display from it.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the *`style`* attribute containing **`display: none;`** you need to use `removeAttribute()` inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `presence_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.g-recaptcha-response#g-recaptcha-response[name='g-recaptcha-response']"))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('style')", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@class='g-recaptcha-response' and @id='g-recaptcha-response'][@name='g-recaptcha-response']"))))
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on date in zebra datepicker in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577003/how-to-click-on-date-in-zebra-datepicker-in-html/57577612#57577612)
- [How to send a date directly as text to a calendar control with readonly attribute using Selenium through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449375/how-to-send-a-date-directly-as-text-to-a-calendar-control-with-readonly-attribut/57453876#57453876)
- [How to Change a html line code with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731966/how-to-change-a-html-line-code-with-python/64732027#64732027)