# Trying to remove html readonly attribute using python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to remove readonly tag from an input field by using python and selenium. Can anybody help me here?

Datepicker Image:

[image: date]

HTML:

```html
<input id="startDate" name="START_DATE" type="text" class="date hasDatepicker" readonly="readonly">
```

Code I've tried :

```py
driver.execute_script('driver.find_element_by_xpath('"+//*[@id = '"+'startDate'+"']+"').removeAttribute("readonly")')
```

Comment: What happens when you run that piece of code? Also, do you want to remove both `readonly="readonly"` or just attribute value ?

Comment: I'll need to remove both so that i can place in inputs that is why. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the *`readonly`* attribute you need to use [*removeAttribute()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57449375/how-to-send-a-date-directly-as-text-to-a-calendar-control-with-readonly-attribut/57453876#57453876) as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='date hasDatepicker' and @id='startDate']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('readonly')", element)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to Change a html line code with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731966/how-to-change-a-html-line-code-with-python/64732027#64732027)
- [How to click on date in zebra datepicker in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57577003/how-to-click-on-date-in-zebra-datepicker-in-html/57577612#57577612)