# Replacing image on the website locally using selenium libraries

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'd like to open Google using Selenium webdriver and replace the Google logo with some other image. Of course I don't mean to change it on the server I want to do it locally in my web browser.

Is it doable?

Comment: Why selenium?.. It is a testing tool, I don't think that image switch is something connected with testing. You can do it via JS in 1-2 lines though..

Comment: I want to get live version of google that's why i use selenium to open it with webdriver then i want to replace image and do some more actions with selenium.

Comment: Add some JS that will replace an attribute with the value you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium - in your case this attribute will be the img value.

Comment: @ConstantineNovykov why don't you turn the comment into an answer, and the OP can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some JS that will replace an attribute with the value you need: [Selenium: Can I set any of the attribute value of a WebElement in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium) - in your case this attribute will be the img `src` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript executor to change the properties of the WebPage.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='lga']//img"));    
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].src='"+pathToNewImage+"'", imageElement);
```