# Selenium: Open Link in Same Tab

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am clicking a link via Selenium webdriver and the link opens up a new windows - I want to force the link to open in the same window (and the same tab) is this possible?

Most of the time this does not happen only with a specific link..

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Before clicking the link update the link's **target** property to **self** and then click it.

For updating the property please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium).

Comment: I had to use `_self`, rather than `self`, to get this trick working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See if the HTML code is like below, link will open in a different tab/windows depending upon the browser settings.

```
<a href = "#" target = "_blank">
```

When a `Firefox` browser is launched via Selenium Webdriver, the default profile it launches by default has [this](http://puu.sh/m26kb/c335fbd885.png) option enabled. You can create a new firefox profile by disabling this option. In this case the link will open in the same firefox window.

In `Chrome` driver, new links open in the same window itself.

You can force selenium webdriver to open a link in the same window but to open the link in same tab I don't think you can force it directly without injecting some `Javascript`. Using `Javascript` you can update the attribute `target` to complete your requirement.

If you want to inject Javascript you can use [`JavaScriptExecutor`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html) from `Selenium Webdriver API`.

```
((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("document.getElementById('ID').setAttribute('target', 'self');")
```

Comment: Hi Paras, I have similar problem and I tried to set attribute like driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', 'self')", el)
    el.click() but no luck I can still see multiple windows. Any more suggestions?

Comment: tell me what issue you are facing.

Comment: Please refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611045/python-selenium-opens-a-new-window-on-click-instead-of-tab

Answer (score 0):

#### For **single-dom** element

```
@driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('your_css_element')[#{index}].setAttribute('target','_blank')")
```

#### For **multi-dom** elements

```
 your_list_of_elements.each_with_index do |elem, index|
      @driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('your_css_element')[#{index}].setAttribute('target','_blank')")
 end
```

(**note**: the above is a ruby snippet, apply the same in your preferred lang.)

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.addPreference("browser.link.open_newwindow", 1);               
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!