# Python Selenium opens a new window on click instead of tab

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am trying to download some files with python selenium after authentication, but when selenium clicks the file link it opens a new window and therefore it is asking for authentication again. Can I force selenium to download file without opening new window or in new tab using same auth?

```
elementList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("file-link")
for el in elementList:
    el.click()
```

Update 1:

```
elementList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("file-link")
for el in elementList:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('target', 'self')", el)
    el.click()
```

But still getting multiple windows.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from [this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34378449/selenium-open-link-in-same-tab)

Comment: Yes I setAttribute target to self. But its not working.

Comment: Another workaround is, call directly URL which download a resource from the server. You can get URL directly from DOM element. Example:
 https://mysite/section/dummy/file.txt with python (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)