# Selenium Webdriver Java - Create button and push it

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using **Selenium Webdriver** (Chrome & Firefox) with ***Java*** .

After making all kind of actions, I came across a regular source code like this :

```
<input type="button" value="yoyo" class="btn" onClick="SubmitForm(this, 'XYZ','_blank')" >
```

and I need to push the button..  but before pushing the button (regularly), I need to change the "XYZ" to "ABC". Is there any way to do that?

Or maybe creating a **new button** or a **form** and then push it?

Or even use javascript somehow.. anything will do.

I could not find any information on how to do this, I will be thankful for your help.

Comment: Usually one would use Selenium to interact with a web page as presented from the server. Are you asking about how to manipulate the content of the page while using Selenium, so that Selenium can then operate on the modified page?

Comment: Yep ..
As I mentioned, I have to press a button when one of the values is different.
I know this is not the goal of the tool, but if it can do that it will  help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it during runtime automation then `click` using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.className("btn"))

((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('onClick', arguments[1]);arguments[0].click();", el, "SubmitForm(this, 'ABC','_blank')");
```

**Note**:- This will not effect as permanently solution. this effect will work on the page until the page not refresh.

Hope it will work..:)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the JavascriptExecutor as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8476765/62462

```
WebDriver driver; // Assigned elsewhere
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('//id of element').setAttribute('onClick', 'SubmitForm(this, \'ABC\',\'_blank\')')");
```

You might need to find the input element via XPath if it doesn't have an id.