# How to set attribute to using selenium javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to set attribute to a slider. I am using javascript to automate, I have currently tried the below code,

```
it('should pan plots when you click and drag', function(done) {
                driver.sleep(2000);

                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('._md-slider-wrapper')).click().then(function(){
                driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css('._md-thumb-container')).SetAttribute("style", "left: 22px");
                    done();
                });
```

but it is not working. I have also tried to pass the element to a function and then try to set the attribute but it didnt work either. i am basically trying to set the value to a slider.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium

Comment: @user2987322, just extract `Javacsript` line from provided `JavaScriptExecutor` code. There is no other possibility to change element's attribute using `selenium`, except with `JavascriptExecutor`, but as long as you use pure `JavaScript` you don't need "executors"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
driver.executeScript("document.querySelector('._md-thumb-container').setAttribute('style', 'left: 22px'");
```

Comment: If you open the page google.com, and type the commands below in the inspector, what will you see?
`document.querySelector("#q")`;

`document.querySelector("#q").setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false')`;

`document.querySelector("#q")`;

I used the 2nd command to change the attribute `aria-hidden`.

For your case, maybe you should try the same to test whether it works or not.