# Changing an inspect element with selenium java/JavaScript console?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, element

I'm trying to use the selenium chrome driver on Java and part of my script requires me to edit a google chrome element of a website.

**How can I modify the value of this element using java?**

I figured out I'm supposed to use this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

js.executeScript("script here");
```

But I'm not sure what to put in the `js.executeScript` part? I'm pretty sure its javscript but I'm unfamiliar with javascript and could not figure out how to edit this element using it.

This is the element in attempting to change:

[image: Element is circled]

**What would be the javascript line that could change that circled element?**

If you need any further information I would be glad to provide it.

Comment: Put the page source in the question, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the element in this way and then modify it in the way you want. Unless you mention what modification, this is how you can get the element.

```js
var element = document.querySelector('[data-productid="505595887"]')
```

document.querySelector('[data-productid="505595887"]') is the js code you need to execute.

Comment: How can I set it to be a number like "50" instead of "505595887"?

Comment: use this code to set ti 50 or any value:

document.querySelector('[data-productid="505595887"]').setAttribute("data-productid","50")

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium)