# Selenium VBA change Attribute

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

this is my html code:

```
<input id="drugCodeId_focus" name="drugCodeId_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="drugCodeId_items" aria-activedescendant="drugCodeId_25" aria-describedby="drugCodeId_25" aria-disabled="false">
```

this is a combobox and after change attribute value of "aria-activedescendant" and "aria-describedby" value of combobox will change.
help me for change for expample value "drugCodeId_25" to "drugCodeId_26".

Comment: This looks like HTML. What has it to do with VBA?

Comment: yes i wan to make a bot to change value combobox

Comment: Where are your code attempts? Trying to change attributes on an element is a sure way to cause unexpected behavior on the site. Instead of attempting to change element attributes, instead do whatever you are trying to do using steps a user would perform then automate those steps.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need this

```vb
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//input[@id='drugCodeId_focus']").SendKeys("your text here")
```

Comment: sendKeys for wich attribute?  this id ("drugCodeId_focus") has a lot of attribute i want to change one them. this attribute ("aria-activedescendant")

Comment: see if this helps: -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473024/selenium-can-i-set-any-of-the-attribute-value-of-a-webelement-in-selenium

Comment: OP is asking how to change an attribute of the element, not send keys to that element