# selenium returning error element not found while the xpath is present in the page code

Tags: perl, selenium, xpath

i am trying to automate the web application in perl using selenium module,
i m using selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0 on firefox version 27.0,

while i run my script i get error at this line

```
$sel->click_ok("//g[contains(\@class,'highcharts-series-group')]//rect");
```

the HTML for this is :

```
<g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
<g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(27,20) scale(1 1)" style="cursor:pointer;" clip-path="url(#highcharts-347)">
<rect fill="rgb(86,161,220)" x="478" y="34" width="25" height="167" fill-opacity="1" rx="4" ry="4">
</g>
<g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(27,20) scale(1 1)">
</g>
```

> i am getting error : ERROR: Element //g[contains(@class,'highcharts-series-group')//rect] not found

Thanks in advance

sample :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<script type="text/javascript">
var rand="1390977827";
</script>
</head>
<body class="rdx_auto_cursor">
<div class="chart" data-highcharts-chart="1">
<div id="highcharts-2" class="highcharts-container" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 1029px; height: 250px; text-align: left; line-height: normal; z-index: 0; font-family: "Lucida Grande","Lucida Sans Unicode",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; left: 0.199997px; top: 0.199997px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1029" height="250">
<desc>Created with Highcharts 3.0.2</desc>
<defs>
<clipPath id="highcharts-3">
<rect fill="none" x="1" y="1" width="980" height="198">
</rect>
</clipPath>
</defs>
<g class="highcharts-series-group" zIndex="3">
<g class="highcharts-series highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker highcharts-tracker" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(27,20) scale(1 1)" style="cursor:pointer;" clip-path="url(#highcharts-3)">
<rect fill="rgb(86,161,220)" x="478" y="100" width="25" height="100" fill-opacity="1" rx="4" ry="4">
</rect>
</g>
<g class="highcharts-markers" visibility="visible" zIndex="0.1" transform="translate(27,20) scale(1 1)">
</g>
</g>
</svg>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: contains is not required if you are using the whole class name..just `//g[@class='highcharts-series-group']//rect` would work...

Comment: @amith even if i dont use contains then also the its giving same error.

Comment: @amith I would always use contains when using class in an xpath as classes can be added and removed. Unlike css selectors, xpath treats class as a literal string not a collection of values

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to click on an SVG element right?

See http://www.qaautomation.net/?p=388 "XPath namespaces"

Try this expression:

```
//*[local-name()='g']
   [contains(@*[local-name()='class'],'highcharts-series-group')]
   //*[local-name()='rect']
```

Maybe there's a way to register the SVG namespace and then use

```
//svg:g[contains(@svg:class,'highcharts-series-group')]//svg:rect
```

---

A more verbose of this would be:

```
//*[local-name()='g' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']
   [contains(
        @*[local-name()='class' and namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'],
       'highcharts-series-group')]
   //*[local-name()='rect']
```

Comment: Found out another question that might help also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398172/selenium-svg-element-embedded-into-object-tag-is-not-been-identified-by-seleniu

Comment: yes i m trying to click on the svg element, i tried your given xpath ,in that case also it returning the same error.

Comment: would you have a sample page link to share?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium but the first expression I proposed works for me with Python's `lxml`. Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592213/selenium-webdriver-clicking-on-elements-within-an-svg-using-xpath (try replacing "local-name()" with "name()")