# Accesing the namespace of node in xslt

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

Source:

```
    <Data>
    <heading xmlns="Some Uri">
                <text>aaa</text>


    </heading>
    <Data>
```

XSLT wrote

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:link1="Some Uri">
                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

                  <xsl:template match="Data">
                    <xsl:value-of select="link1:heading/namespace-uri()"/>

                  </xsl:template>


            </xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting error.

Can any one help how to do get the namespace.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `namespace-uri()`
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529556/xpath-find-elements-by-attribute-namespace

Comment: Your input XML is not value (extra `</text>`).

Answer (score 1):

nonnb should have made the comment an answer...

The namespace-uri() function does what you want.

Comment: I tried with that I am getting errors. I have edited the question with the thing I have done.

Comment: I have edited the question and I am unable to get the name space of the node. Can you help me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <xsl:value-of select="link1:heading/namespace-uri()"/>
> ```

**In XSLT 1.0 / XPath 1.0 this is a syntax error**.

**Correct this to**:

```
<xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri(link1:heading)"/>
```

**In XSLT 2.0 / XPath 2.0 this again is an error (the argument for `namespace-uri()` cannot be ommitted. Correct to:**

```
<xsl:value-of select="link1:heading/namespace-uri(.)"/>
```

Comment: I think select="link1:heading/namespace-uri()" should work in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @MichaelKay: Maybe you are right -- I find it difficult and unnecessary to remember exactly which functions can have their argument omitted and which not -- so it is safer to always provide the argument.